What can I do to make it as hard/expensive as possible for a hacker if I've detected a malicious DDOS request?
I want to implement some sort of an Under Attack Mode for our application.
Of course I could use CloudFlare or any other solutions, but let's say for the sake of a programming exercise I detect a malicious request - i.e. because they don't contain a valid cookie that they could have had if they solved a CAPTCHA of some sort.
What would be the best way to make it as difficult/expensive as possible for the attacker?
Of course I make sure these request are detected as early as possible in the request pipeline. But what should I do next?
Just return as fast as possible?
Or is there something I can do that is super resource intensive for them, but not for me?
In example:
can I act like the connection is still open and I will send a response any minute now, but will never send anything anymore and I already closed the connection on my side?
So causing timeouts and open connections on their side while I don't take any hits.
I'm using ASP.NET Core on Azure.

I strongly recommend against any reaction that might be viewed as malicious itself. Just because a user sends an unexpected request doesn't mean they're an attacker. They could have done this by accident (e.g., because browser extension messes with the website), or maybe their device has been compromised (think of botnets). In the worst case, you end up affecting completely innocent people. This might also turn into a legal problem.
Reject faulty requests as early as possible. For example, set up a reverse proxy which stops requests before they hit the application server or even the application (which usually does a lot of heavy lifting and therefore needs more resources). If the attack exploits a specific weakness in your setup, then it may also be possible to fix this.

Note that this mode would be only manually triggered at the moment there is a very active attack going on. After the attack is passed I would disable it again.

@DirkBoer: Sure, but even during an attack, it's difficult (if not impossible) to distinguish between actual attackers, victims whose device is being exploited for a DoS attack and innocent users who just happen to visit the site at the wrong time. This is why any offensive counter-measure is very problematic.

The plan was doing a sort of one-time puzzle/captcha. "Sorry we are temporarily under attack. Can you help us by solving this puzzle to proof you are human and not part of the bot network attacking us" - after that they get normal access. It looks like CloudFlare / Vercel use something similar.

CAPTCHAs are fine.
